# How can I make it so when a page width is reduced, it eventually stops adjusting?

Tags: css, browser, window, width

This is kind of hard to explain... Take any major website, CNN.com, Weather.com, etc. and when you pull your browser from the left or right to reduce the window width, the page moves, adjusts to keep the header centered and things like that...

After a point, though, the page stops adjusting, because any more adjusting and the header won't be able to fit, the hyperlinks will overlap onto the next line and it'll look terrible...

What's the code that makes that happen?  I would guess "min-width", however I'm having no luck with that.

Comment: If your playing with the min-width remember that margin and padding are included.

Comment: Can you post your HTML structure?

Answer (score 1):

Through CSS you have `min-width` and `max-width` *attributes*.

**max-width**: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp

This attribute will represent the maximum `width` supported by the element. So what ever forced size or content it contains, this *value* will be the maximum size this element's width can be.

**min-width**: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp

This attribute will represent the minimum `width` supported by the element. So what ever resize or forced reductions of this element's size, this *value* will be the minimum size this element's width can be.

---

These attributes are usually used to control element sizes on cases just as yours, ensuring that the user has the best visual experience possible.

**More detailed info on these attributes and nice ways to use them:** http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/width.html

Answer (score 1):

By default, a block level container's width will be 100% of its parent unless defined otherwise. The effect you're referring to is achieved just by explicitly setting the pixel width of a container (such as a DIV), and then centering that container. The browser will add equal margin to the left and right of that container, keeping it in the center as long as the window is larger that the width you've specified. When the browser window becomes less that the width you specified, the container will anchor to the left edge of the window and a horizontal scroll bar will appear, allowing you to scroll to the right.

In the case of CNN.com, for the content, there is a wrapper DIV with no classes or ID's but the attribute "align=center". Inside that container is a DIV with id="cnn_maincntnr". That container has width: 1000px, which is defined in hplib-min.css.

Comment: You know CNN.com very well!  I knew I was on the right track with min-width, but this clarifies some things, and elaborates, which I appreciate, thank you!

Comment: ...Though I'm a little uncertain about the difference between CSS such as this and making a site "responsive"... Am I correct in saying that this CSS is for the desktop and laptop experience, and "responsive" code, such as Bootstrap or HTML5 Boilerplate, is more for phones and tablets and works in conjunction with @media?

Comment: Yep. Making a site "responsive" means that the layout will "[respond to the user’s behavior and environment based on screen size, platform and orientation](http://bit.ly/m3ap1L)", so this does not disclude the desktop/laptop experience.

You're correct; setting a static width, as in the CNN example, is normally a technique which targets larger screens (desktop/laptop), and we can do that with a media query (@media, like you said). Then for smaller screens, we normally use an "elastic" layout, which shrinks and stretches using percentage widths instead of explicit pixel declarations.

Comment: I think the key is that both of these approaches together create a responsive layout. Another way to do this, as mentioned in some of the other responses, is to give your container a width: 100% (the default for non-floated block level elements) and a max-width: 1000px.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. I outlined where your content will go by a yellow border just so you could see what it would look like. Check out the example to see if that layout is what you want and if it is check out the code.

### [Example](http://jsbin.com/APucIde/2/)

### [CODE](http://jsbin.com/APucIde/2/edit)

Tell me what you think or tell me if this didn't work out for you.

Suprisingly no min-width necessary if you noticed.

**EDIT:**

Here's what you need to do to put padding in.  You just have to add inner-wrappers and put padding on those. I added content (just to show what it would look like with content) and took the height off of the divs so that they would just have height auto (fit to their contents).  Yeah now it's probably too much markup now to the extent it might be confusing but it illustrates that it has padding now.

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/APucIde/7/edit)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for... It's basically min-width, but as you said, it's not... I mean another way of achieving much the same thing.  Would this be better to use?  I will say it would solve the issue I have where <div> lines (section dividers) don't adjust with the page's width if it goes wider than "100%", but I think I can solve that by putting everything in a div container...

Comment: This honestly does have some caveats to it since it uses the background-color on the inner and outer wrapper you can fix this and take off the background-color if you set a min-width on the outer-wrapper of all the sections #header, #main-content, #nav then you shouldn't have to set the background on both wrappers anymore which means you could use a gradient just like cnn. So just set a min-width on those and you have something very similar to cnn's site.  I could make a new mockup if you want. I use this method but there is a lot of markup when you want padding on the left and right sides.

Comment: I won't make you do that for me, thank you though!  I think I get what you're saying... I think it'll cause more problems than it'll fix since I actually have a background-image set for body (which, since undefined in the HTML code for pages, just encompasses the entire page).

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact "min-width"!

For those who are wondering the same thing in the future, simply assign certain elements in your CSS file with the tag "min-width" and then something like 1200px (most displays are at least that big, might go 1100 to be safe like if the taskbar (Windows) or dock (OS X) are on a side, so: "min-width:1100px".

It'd vary by site, but for me I put "min-width:1100px" in the body element of my primary CSS file.

And then too if you have a responsive site, it'd be a percent or em instead of px...